# Holt-Winters in r with function hw. Question on value of beta parameter and forecasting phase

Tags: r, forecast, holtwinters

I have used the function hw to analyze a time series

```
fcast<-hw(my_series,h=12,level=95,seasonal="multiplicative",damped=TRUE,lambda=NULL)
```

By looking at the fcast$model$par I observe the values of alpha, beta, gamma, phi, and the initial states.
I've also looked at the contents of fcast$model$states to see the evolution of all the values. I've tried to reproduce the results in Excel in order to understand the whole procedure.
To achieve the same values of b (trend) as in fcast$model$states I observe that I have to use a formula like the one in the bibliography about the Holt-Winters method:

```
b(t)=beta2*(l(t)-l(t-1)+(1-beta2)*phi*b(t-1)
```

But, if in fcast$model$par beta=0.08128968, I find that in order to achieve the same results I have to use beta2=0.50593541.

What's the reason for that? I don't see any relationship between beta and beta2.

I have also found that in order to get the same forecast as the one obtained with the hw function I have to use the following formulas once the data are finished:

```
l(t)=l(t-1)+b(t-1)
b(t)=phi*b(t-1)
^y(t)=(l(t-1)+b(t-1))*s(t-m)
```

I haven't found any bibliography on this forecasting phase, explaining that some parameters are no longer used. For instance, in this case phi is still used for b(t), but not used anymore for l(t).
Can anyone refer to any bibliography where I can find this part explained?

So in the end I've been able to reproduce the whole set of data in Excel, but there's a couple of steps I would like to understand better.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you add some example data to your post so people can reproduce this more easily? It might also be worthwhile to link to the specific resource you're referencing here.

Comment: I've continued investigating and I have found my problem.

The forecast provides beta, but we need beta*.
beta*=beta/alfa, as is for other similar examples shown in section 7.5 here: [link](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ets.html)